# Definition of "relative permutation" from a computer vision paper

Tags: matrices, permutations, definition

I'm reading through this [CVPR paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Birdal_Probabilistic_Permutation_Synchronization_Using_the_Riemannian_Structure_of_the_Birkhoff_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf). There's this definition I don't quite understand

> **Definition 3** (Relative permutation).  We define a permutation matrix to be relative if it is the ratio (or difference) of two group elements $(i\to j)$ : $P_{ij} = P_i P_j^T$

I'm not really sure what they mean, but isn't then every permutation matrix a relative one? because if $P_i$ is any matrix then we have $P_i = P_i I^T$, where $I$ is the identity and the identity is a permutation matrix.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 1):

In the definition, only one matrix appears, $P$. In your equation, $P$ and $I$ appear, i.e. two different matrices.

That is, the definition does **not** say that a permutation matrix is relative if there exists **some** permutation matrix $Q$ such that $P_{ij} = P_iQ_j^T$

Comment: Not sure I follow,what do you mean with "only matrix appears"? There's no constraint saying that $P_{ij}, P_i, P_j$ have to be different. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user8469759 $P_{ij}$ is an element of the matrix $P$. $P_i$ is a column of that **same matrix**. If $A$ is a matrix, then $A_i$ is standard notation for "the $i$-th column of $A$". So yes, there **is** a constraint on $P_{ij}, P_i, P_j$.. Not that they are equal, but that they are from the same matrix.

Comment: If you look at *definition* 2 in the paper we have a summation of $P_i$ where $P_i \in \mathcal{P}_n$ and in that context it is clear that $P_i$ is actually a matrix. In definition 3 also we have $P_i P_j^T$, one is a column vector and the other is a row vector therefore it must be a $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: @user8469759 I see. Then I agree with you that the paper is confusingly written, however I don't have the time to read through it all just to understand the context. sorry I can't be of more help...